# How to group grid data or configure a tree-like structure based on business object properties in an XAF ListView

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress, xaf

[image]I have been having super difficulties on creating a view that will display my data grouped in levels (Screenshot attached).

I don't know on how to go about this, my data is stored in **ONE single table** in database which is mapped to a business object in application. Therefore what I want is to **group elements based on PROPERTIES** (attributes of table) , for instance, group level one based on first property etc.

Probably some of you may have worked previously on devexpress and have some suggestions.

It would be extremely helpful if you could help on this.

Thank you !!!

Comment: [WHY ARE WE WHISPERING](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/17/a7/b5/17a7b50382877712377db4f28e216153--watch-posts.jpg) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DevExpress XAF, these grouping features are already built-in and are provided for both WinForms and ASP.NET WebForms platforms by the corresponding DevExpress grids (GridControl and ASPxGridView respectively). All that you need is to configure them in your application either at runtime or at design time (using the Model Editor tool invoked for XAFML files or by writing code). I demonstrated these approaches in the videos below:
[image: configuration using the Model Editor]
[image: configuration in the end user application]
Just for demo purposes, I used the WinForms app, but the same is also available for Web (e.g., check it yourself within the online demo at https://demos.devexpress.com/XAF/MainDemo/. Moreover, you can configure it once for both platforms at the YourSolutionName.Module project level.

You can learn more about these features from the corresponding online DevExpress documentation:
[UI Customization > Apply Grouping to List View Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/112826/Getting-Started/Comprehensive-Tutorial/UI-Customization/Apply-Grouping-to-List-View-Data)
[Concepts > Application Model > Model Editor > Ways to Invoke the Model Editor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113326/Concepts/Application-Model/Model-Editor/Ways-to-Invoke-the-Model-Editor)

Answer (score -1):

I am not going to write any code but I hope this hint could help you:

You can have a look at the [Extended WPF Toolkit™](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/). The Community Edition is licensed under the Microsoft Public License and simple to get as nuget. One feature is a powerful and easy to implement [DataGrid](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home) which also allows to group and order the items by properties:

[image]

There are a lot of examples in the web and also a good introduction and overview at [Codeplex](http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Where is the problem @Puppy? This answer gives the hint of using the Extended WPF Toolkit, which could definitively solve the question, combined with links to further information. Since the question is not adding some specific information it is not possible to give a more specific answer. I don't see any reason to downvote this.